# Can you help me find the voltage drop for R3 and R4 on the following circuit

Tags: voltage

Circuit:  my teacher says the voltage drop is 1.5V each.  I don’t know how he gets that answer.  Here is my work thus far.  I get 7.5V for each.  Please let me know where I am going wrong.  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: YOu need to show us your work/

Comment: I.e. what did you get for current through each and why?

Comment: Solve for the voltage at the junction of R1 and R2, then the answer should be apparent from that.

Comment: Where are you going wrong? In step 7, you have \$E_{R3} = E_{t} - E_{R2}\$, which must be wrong since R2 ja R3 are in parallel branches, and parallel branches have the same voltage over them. (Of course there's R5 in the same branch as R3/R4, too, but that doesn't matter with the relation between R2 and R3)

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this without calculating currents at all.

You already did the hard part and correctly calculated R2345 as 3.6R

Now you have a voltage divider with R1 from the 12V, so...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYE38U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$V_{R2} = 12 * 3.6 / 9.6 = 4.5V\$

Since R34 = 3 and R5 is 6, again a simple voltage divider,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3M9vy.png)</sup>

\$V_{R34} = 4.5 * 3/9 =1.5V\$

Answer (score 2):

I used another method, Don't always go for the current. It's waste of time when your circuit is already simplied.

Here you have two 6 ohm resistors in parellel which give equivalent of 3 ohm. (6||6)
This 3 ohm is in series with 6 ohm resistor and their result is in parellel with 6 ohm resistor ,which gives 3.6 ohms as their equivalent. ((3+6) || 6 ) . The total is now 3.6+6 ohms .

Therefore voltage drop across 3.6 ohm resisor ( as we need to find voltage drop of that branch ) is 12*3.6/(3.6+6) = 4.5 volts. Similarly now split the resisors . We have 4.5 across a 9 ohm resistor and 6 ohm resistor which were in parallel .

As you need to find voltage across the 3 ohm (6 || 6) and 6ohm , the same formula ,4.5*3(3+6) = 1.5 volts

Answer (score 0):

1 - Assume your current is correct.
2 - Calculate the voltage drop across R1.
3 - Subtract this from 12 to get the voltage across R2.
4 - Calculate the effective resistance of R3/R4.
5 - The ratio of this to R6 gives the ratio of the voltages over R3/R4 and R6. (why?)
6 - Apply this ratio to the result of step 3.